# How to skin Appcelerator Titanium apps?

Tags: maven, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm new on appcelerator and I counldn't find a satisfying answer.

My problem is that I need to create two mobile apps with about 80-90% of common.

In fact it consist in a login page which differs in skin and url, then it's just a webview with the same properties. There might be some more differencies in the future.

So I'm searching if it's possible on appcelerator to use something like maven to define build parameters to build both app with only one project. There might be some built-in functions but I haven't found one...

I'm open to any solution ;)

Comment: Not really an answer but did you look at Codename One? It's based on Ant for the build system so I'm pretty sure something like Maven can be plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

With Appcelerator Titanium the best way to go is using the [Alloy MVC](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Framework) which has support for [themes](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Styles_and_Themes). You can then switch between different "brands" of your app before you do a build by setting a single property in the `app/config.json` file (or do so via Grunt/Gulp script).